# Telerik RadPropertyGrid Content of CollectionEditorPicker

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, propertygrid

as the topic suggests I wan't to modify the Content of the CollectionEditorPicker. This control is used to open the floating Window for the List of nested Properties.
Unfortunally the RadPropertyGrid don't show any Information about the collection in the Field.
How can I set some value in there? For example a placeholder like "Click here to open the collection" or "xx Items" or "Item 1, Item 2, Item 3..." so see some preview or Information about the field.

I've tried it with a template Selector, but if I'm doing so, the opened Popup is not resizable anymore. Also it looses some Information which are in the default CollectionEditorPicker.
Can you help me?

Below a minimal working Example.

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TelerikPropertyGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:model="clr-namespace:TelerikPropertyGridTest.Model"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <model:TemplateSelector x:Key="RadPropertyListTemplateSelector">
                <!-- Not Working -->
                <model:TemplateSelector.CollectionsDataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <telerik:RadDropDownButton Content="Test">
                               <telerik:RadDropDownButton.DropDownContent>
                                   <telerik:CollectionEditor telerik:AutoBindBehavior.UpdateBindingOnElementLoaded="Source"
                                                             ></telerik:CollectionEditor>
                               </telerik:RadDropDownButton.DropDownContent>
                           </telerik:RadDropDownButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </model:TemplateSelector.CollectionsDataTemplate>
                <model:TemplateSelector.FloatNumberTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadNumericUpDown telerik:AutoBindBehavior.UpdateBindingOnElementLoaded="Value" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </model:TemplateSelector.FloatNumberTemplate>
                <model:TemplateSelector.IntNumberTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadNumericUpDown telerik:AutoBindBehavior.UpdateBindingOnElementLoaded="Value"
                                                  NumberDecimalDigits="0" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </model:TemplateSelector.IntNumberTemplate>
            </model:TemplateSelector>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <telerik:RadPropertyGrid Item="{Binding ObjectToBind}" 
                                 AutoGeneratingPropertyDefinition="RadPropertyGrid_OnAutoGeneratingPropertyDefinition"
                                 EditorTemplateSelector="{StaticResource RadPropertyListTemplateSelector}">
        </telerik:RadPropertyGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The ViewModel (generates a Random Object for testing)

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{

    private readonly Random _random = new Random();

    private IExampleInterface _objectToBind;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.ObjectToBind = new ExampleImplementation
                            {
                                SomeBooleanValue = this._random.Next() % 2 == 1,
                                SomeDateValue = this.RandomDay(),
                                SomeIntValue = this._random.Next(),
                                SomeString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                SubClasses = new List<IExampleInterface>
                                             {
                                                 new ExampleImplementation
                                                 {
                                                     SomeBooleanValue = this._random.Next() % 2 == 1,
                                                     SomeDateValue = this.RandomDay(),
                                                     SomeIntValue = this._random.Next(),
                                                     SomeString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                                     SubClasses = new List<IExampleInterface>
                                                                  {
                                                                      new ExampleImplementation
                                                                      {
                                                                          SomeBooleanValue =
                                                                              this._random.Next() % 2 == 1,
                                                                          SomeDateValue = this.RandomDay(),
                                                                          SomeIntValue = this._random.Next(),
                                                                          SomeString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                 }
                                             }
                            };
    }

    public IExampleInterface ObjectToBind
    {
        get { return this._objectToBind; }
        set
        {
            if (this._objectToBind != value)
            {
                this._objectToBind = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("ObjectToBind");
            }
        }
    }

    private DateTime RandomDay()
    {
        var start = new DateTime(1995, 1, 1);
        var range = (DateTime.Today - start).Days;
        return start.AddDays(this._random.Next(range));
    }

}
```

The IExampleInterface (should be later on a real Interface):

```
public interface IExampleInterface
{
    string SomeString { get; set; }
    int SomeIntValue { get; set; }
    double SomeDouble { get; set; }
    IList<IExampleInterface> SubClasses { get; set; }
    IList<IExampleInterface> SubClasses2 { get; set; }
    bool SomeBooleanValue { get; set; }
    DateTime SomeDateValue { get; set; }
    SomeEnum SomeEnumValue { get; set; }
}
```

The ExampleImplementation (should have later on a Real Implementation with additional Properties).

```
public class ExampleImplementation : BindableBase, IExampleInterface
{

    private bool _someBooleanValue;
    private DateTime _someDateValue;
    private double _someDouble;
    private SomeEnum _someEnumValue;
    private int _someIntValue;
    private string _someString;
    private ObservableCollection<IExampleInterface> _subClasses;

    private ObservableCollection<IExampleInterface> _subClasses2;

    public bool SomeBooleanValue
    {
        get { return this._someBooleanValue; }
        set
        {
            if (this._someBooleanValue != value)
            {
                this._someBooleanValue = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SomeBooleanValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public DateTime SomeDateValue
    {
        get { return this._someDateValue; }
        set
        {
            if (this._someDateValue != value)
            {
                this._someDateValue = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SomeDateValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public double SomeDouble
    {
        get { return this._someDouble; }
        set
        {
            if (Math.Abs(this._someDouble - value) > 0.01)
            {
                this._someDouble = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SomeDouble");
            }
        }
    }

    public SomeEnum SomeEnumValue
    {
        get { return this._someEnumValue; }
        set
        {
            if (this._someEnumValue != value)
            {
                this._someEnumValue = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SomeEnumValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public int SomeIntValue
    {
        get { return this._someIntValue; }
        set
        {
            if (this._someIntValue != value)
            {
                this._someIntValue = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SomeIntValue");
            }
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = @"TestString", GroupName = @"TestGroup", Description = @"TestDescription")]
    public string SomeString
    {
        get { return this._someString; }
        set
        {
            if (this._someString != value)
            {
                this._someString = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SomeString");
            }
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = @"Some Subclasses")]
    public IList<IExampleInterface> SubClasses
    {
        get { return this._subClasses; }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(this._subClasses, value))
            {
                this._subClasses = new ObservableCollection<IExampleInterface>(value);
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SubClasses");
            }
        }
    }

    public IList<IExampleInterface> SubClasses2
    {
        get { return this._subClasses2; }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(this._subClasses2, value))
            {
                this._subClasses2 = new ObservableCollection<IExampleInterface>(value);
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SubClasses2");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And finally the TemplateSelector

```
  public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var def = item as PropertyDefinition;
        if (def == null || def.SourceProperty == null)
        {
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }

        if (typeof (IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(def.SourceProperty.PropertyType) && typeof(string) != def.SourceProperty.PropertyType)
        {
            return this.CollectionsDataTemplate;
        }

        if (typeof (double).IsAssignableFrom(def.SourceProperty.PropertyType))
        {
            return this.FloatNumberTemplate;
        }

        if (typeof (int).IsAssignableFrom(def.SourceProperty.PropertyType))
        {
            return this.IntNumberTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }

    public DataTemplate CollectionsDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FloatNumberTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate IntNumberTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

[This is what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa7Km.png)

The optimal solution would be to get detailed Information in the TextBlock, like Item 1, item 2 etc.

Thank you.

**// Edit:**
I've figured out the NullReferenceException and got a Demo to work, so that I can modify the text. But the popup is different to the default. Have you an idea to fix it?

I've updated the text and the example.

Comment: I have noticed, the RadPropertyGrid calls standard 'string ToString()' method as soon as it hits a subclass of a class. In case its a collection, nothing is shown in that description field. However, if you call ToString() on an ObservableCollection, it does return appropriate namespaces and class names - as expected. I wonder whether this is because ToString() is not called in case of ObservableCollection at all (by Telerik decision), or rather because some other implementation of ToString() down the polymorphic stack is called.

Comment: If your sub-classes are collections, you can derive your own class with overriden ToString(). Override ToString() as extension method won't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wasting a few hours now I figured out a solution to realize this.

I've added a custom behavior to the Collection template. This behavior sets the Header of the CollectionEditor as soon as it's loaded or updated.

Below you can see my modifications:

The Template:

```
<model:TemplateSelector.CollectionsDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <telerik:RadDropDownButton Content="Click to edit the collection">
            <telerik:RadDropDownButton.DropDownContent>
                <telerik:CollectionEditor telerik:AutoBindBehavior.UpdateBindingOnElementLoaded="Source"
                                          ResizeGripperVisibility="Visible">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <model:CollectionEditorBehavior />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </telerik:CollectionEditor>
            </telerik:RadDropDownButton.DropDownContent>
        </telerik:RadDropDownButton>
    </DataTemplate>
</model:TemplateSelector.CollectionsDataTemplate>
```

The behavior:

```
internal class CollectionEditorBehavior : Behavior<CollectionEditor>
{

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.SourceUpdated += (sender, args) => this.PrepareHeader();
        this.AssociatedObject.DataContextChanged += (sender, args) => this.PrepareHeader();
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += (sender, args) => this.PrepareHeader();
    }

    private void PrepareHeader()
    {
        if (this.AssociatedObject == null)
        {
            // Error Case
            return;
        }

        if (this.AssociatedObject.CollectionView == null ||
            this.AssociatedObject.CollectionView.SourceCollection == null)
        {
            // Source not set
            this.AssociatedObject.Header = "Collection";
            return;
        }

        // Get the property from the DataContext to retrieve HeaderInformation
        var propInfo = this.AssociatedObject.DataContext
                           .GetType()
                           .GetProperties()
                           .FirstOrDefault(
                                           propertyInfo =>
                                           Equals(propertyInfo.GetValue(this.AssociatedObject.DataContext),
                                                  this.AssociatedObject.CollectionView.SourceCollection));


        if (propInfo == null)
        {
            // We didn't got the property Information,  using default value
            this.AssociatedObject.Header = "Collection";
            return;
        }

        // Getting the DisplayName Attribute
        var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propInfo,
                                                typeof (DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;

        if (attr != null)
        {
            // We have a DisplayName attribute
            this.AssociatedObject.Header = attr.DisplayName;
            return;
        }

        // Alternative: Get the Display Attribute
        var attr2 = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propInfo,
                                                 typeof (DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
        if (attr2 != null)
        {
            // We have the Display Attribute
            this.AssociatedObject.Header = attr2.Name;
            return;
        }

        // We have no DisplayAttribute and no DisplayName attribute, set it to the PropertyName
        this.AssociatedObject.Header = propInfo.Name;
    }

}
```